How to support hierarchical inheritance in xsdgen tool
I've generated structure in Go language from XSD using xsdgen tool. For example,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
    ...
    <xs:complexType name="BaseRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="GenericObject" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CreateObjectRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BaseRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="createObject" type="GenericObject"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x1="http://example.com" >
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com" schemaLocation=<location of xsd-1/>
    <xs:complexType name="ABC">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="x1:GenericObject">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:schema>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x1="http://example.com" >
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com" schemaLocation=<location of xsd-1/>
    <xs:complexType name="FOO">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="x1:GenericObject">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:schema>

From above XSDs, these Go structures are generated.
type CreateObjectRequest struct {
    element1        string              `xml:"element1"`
    CreateObject    GenericObject       `xml:"createObject"`
}
type GenericObject struct {
    id string `xml:"id"`
}
type ABC struct {
    id       string     `xml:"id"`
    data     string     `xml:"data,omitempty"`
}
type FOO struct {
    id       string     `xml:"id"`
    value    string     `xml:"value,omitempty"`
}

Here type of "CreateObject" in "CreateObjectRequest" structure is "GenericObject". But I want to generate "CreateObjectRequest" structure for derived class ABC and FOO. How can I do so? Is xsdgen support hierarchical inheritance?
